# having problem with reading docx and pptx files from access attachmant field

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that stores files in a attachment field in access database.
Here's the code I use to insert files:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
 Private Sub insert_file(ByVal path As String)
           Dim dbe As New DBEngine
    Dim db As Database = dbe.OpenDatabase(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath &"\Mydatabase.accdb")
    Dim rstrecord As Recordset = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tblfiles where id=1", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    rstrecord.Edit()
    Dim rstattachments As Recordset2 = rstrecord.Fields("File").Value
    rstattachments.AddNew()
    Dim attachmentdata As Field2 = rstattachments.Fields("FileData")
    attachmentdata.LoadFromFile(path)
    rstattachments.Update()
    rstattachments.Close()
    rstrecord.Update()
    rstrecord.Close()
    db.Close()
End Sub
```

and I have a option to export the files.Here is the code:

```
 Private Sub export(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal filestr As String, path As String)
    DS.Reset()
    con = New OleDbConnection(strcon)
    con.Open()

    cmdtxt = "SELECT ID, File.FileName,File.FileType, File.FileData FROM   tblfiles where ID=" & id & " and File.FileName = '" & filestr & "' "


    DA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtxt, con)
    DA.Fill(DS, "tblfiles")
    con.Close()
    Dim savestr As String = path
    Dim byt() As Byte = DS.Tables("tblfiles").Rows(0).Item("File.FileData")
    Try
        File.WriteAllBytes(savestr, byt)
        MessageBox.Show(File exported successfully)
    Catch ex As Exception
  messagebox.show(ex.message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

There is no error in inserting and exporting files but when I export pptx and docx files and I open them I receive the following messages:
docx:The file is corrupt and can not be open.
pptx:powerpoint found a problem with content in file.powerpoint can attempt to repair the presentation.

Comment: Are you sure that the `DataColumn` is actually named "File.FileData"?

Comment: Yes. I can insert and export files without problem but I get into trouble when I want to open pptx and docx files after export and receive the errors in the post.

Comment: If you put any other type of file in there, say an image for example.  Does that get extracted out ok?

Comment: Yes,I just have problem with that files.